# Angular ui-router extend url after path parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-bootstrap

Is this type of routing is possible with ui-router ?

parent state ---> /saved/:id
child state ---> /saved/:id/eat

Bellow is my code snippet. Why I try to do this the page is redirected to route.

```
 .state('frouits.banana.saved', {
        url: '/saved/:id',
        views: {
          parameters: {
            templateUrl: 'banana.html'
          }
        }
      })state('frouits.banana.saved.eat', {
        url: '/saved/:id/eat',
        views: {
          parameters: {
            templateUrl: 'banana.html'
          }
        }
      })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, nested routes in UI-Router are appended. Since `frouits.banana.saved.eat` is a nested view of `frouits.banana.saved`, it inherits its url, which means your route resolved to `/saved/:id/saved/:id/eat`

Thus, all you need to do is remove the `/saved/:id` part from your second route's url.

```
.state('frouits.banana.saved.eat', {
    url: '/eat', // <--
    views: {
      parameters: {
        templateUrl: 'banana.html'
      }
    }
 });
```

The other way that you could have made your initial example work would have been to declare your route as absolute by prepending a caret before your route (`url: '^/saved/:id/eat'`).

For more information on how nested routes work, [refer to the docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#url-routing-for-nested-states).